Browser is not accepting cookie from server with same domain
I have a React js static website in S3,  hosted behind CloudFront at the url - dev.mydomain.com
I have a nodejs server running behind a ELB(load balancer) at the url - api.dev.mydomain.com
I am setting a cookie from server, but browser does not accept the cookie, it does not pass it back to server on subsequent requests. I am setting the cookie in following manner on the server:-
response.cookie('USER_ID','thisisacookie', {
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: 'dev.mydomain.com',
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 9000000, 
});

I have also tried to set domain as .dev.mydomain.com, nothing seems to work. I am not sure what am I missing. Here is how the cookie looks like in the response header:-

Set-Cookie: USER_ID1=YWFvb0Bvb2FhYWEuY29t; Max-Age=9000;
Domain=.dev.mydomain.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 15 May 2024 06:22:45
GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: USER_ID=YWFvb0Bvb2FhYWEuY29t; Max-Age=9000;
Domain=dev.mydomain.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 15 May 2024 06:22:45
GMT; HttpOnly

